# Invite friends to facebook app - android no invitation are send to the selected friend

Tags: android

```
 private void inviteFriends()
    {
        try
        {   
            Bundle params = new Bundle();
            params.putString("title", "invite friends");
            params.putString("message", "come join us!");
            facebook.dialog(this, "apprequests", params, new DialogListener() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(Bundle values) {}

                @Override
                public void onFacebookError(FacebookError error) {}

                @Override
                public void onError(DialogError e) {}

                @Override
                public void onCancel() {}

                public void onComplete(String response, Object state)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        JSONObject eventResponse = new JSONObject(response);
                        //event_id = event.getString("id");
                        Log.i(TAG, "Event Response => "+eventResponse);
                        Log.w("myapp", friends);

                       //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "New Event Created!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {

                    }
                }
            });
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

        }
    }
```

Comment: please add some more description about your requirement.

Comment: can you let me know which facebook sdk you are using ?

Comment: i am using old facebook sdk(Library/Sample facebook code in FBConnwct ).